# .htaccess 301 redirect swedish charcters in target URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I require to write 301 redirect like If URL has /faq then it should redirect to /frågor-svar

I have write redirect rule as

```
redirect 301 /faq <siteURL>/frågor-svar
```

Upon testing it redirects to the specified URL but swedish characters that I entered got changed. It seems URL get encoded and it becomes `/fr%E5gor-svar/`

But In address bar of Browser I need that URL stays as `/frågor-svar/` and not as `/fr%E5gor-svar/`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^faq/?$ frågor-svar [R=301,L,NE]
```